# How to apply background image with linear gradient in Tailwind CSS?

Tags: css, tailwind-css, tailwind-in-js

I want to apply a linear gradient to my background image. on tailwind config file I wrote a custom rule like this:

```
 theme: {
    extend: {
      backgroundImage: (theme) => ({
        'hero-pattern': "url('../src/images/icon-bg.jpg')",
  
      }),
    },
  },
```

It works. but when I try to apply a linear gradient it didn't woork.

For applying linear-gradient, what I have tried is this:

```
 theme: {
    extend: {
      backgroundImage: (theme) => ({
        
         'hero-pattern':
          "linear-gradient(to right bottom, rgba('#7ed56f',0.8), rgba('#28b485',0.8)), url('../src/images/icon-bg.jpg')",
      }),
    },
  },
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: According to docs you only need to add background image to config file. you can use the `linear-gradient` classes directly in your element. https://tailwindcss.com/docs/background-image#background-images

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that you give hex color code within `rgba`. That's why the color is not applied.

You have to give rgba color code instead of hex color code.

Note: Hex color code inside rgba is only supported by SCSS.

Answer (score 20):

don't use function. just try as a utility

```
theme: {
    extend: {
      backgroundImage: {
         'hero-pattern': "linear-gradient(to right bottom, rgba('#7ed56f',0.8), rgba('#28b485',0.8)), url('../src/images/icon-bg.jpg')",
      },
    },
  },
```

here is a working example https://play.tailwindcss.com/uHp6pKIKEc

Comment: Any way to do this using utility classes? Not being able to use the `background` shorthand syntax seems like a shortcoming.

Answer (score 16):

You don't have to tweak config file; Use the following class:

```
bg-[linear-gradient(to_right_bottom,rgba(49,84,44,0.8),rgba(16,71,52,0.8)),url('../src/images/icon-bg.jpg')]
```