# Tailwind Linear Gradient in Image

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

How to apply linear gradient in the image using tailwind,
I tried two version of this code but its not working

This one not working:

```
      <div>
        <img src={BannerImage} alt="BannerImage" className="h-[70vh] lg:h-[80vh] w-full object-cover object-right bg-gradient-to-r from-cyan-500 to-blue-500" />
      </div>
```

This one also not working:

```
      <div className="bg-gradient-to-r from-cyan-500 to-blue-500">
        <img src={BannerImage} alt="BannerImage" className="h-[70vh] lg:h-[80vh] w-full object-cover object-right" />
      </div>
```

[The Result I Want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PEqvj.png)
[The Result I Got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HuxMk.jpg)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67344478/tailwind-css-how-to-apply-background-image-with-linear-gradient

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tailwind CSS: how to apply background image with linear gradient?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67344478/tailwind-css-how-to-apply-background-image-with-linear-gradient)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest I can achieve is this ,

```
<div class="relative mix-blend-overlay">
  <img src="http://codeskulptor-demos.commondatastorage.googleapis.com/GalaxyInvaders/back05.jpg" alt="BannerImage" class="absolute h-[70vh] lg:h-[80vh] w-full object-cover object-right opacity-30 " />
  <div class="absolute -z-10 bg-gradient-to-t from-white via-black to-black h-[70vh] lg:h-[80vh] w-full" />
</div>
```

Refer this https://play.tailwindcss.com/fq9cdlFfCt

Comment: this work exactly what i want

Comment: Glad I am able to help you