# Tailwind not applying a gradient

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

**Update/TLDR:** Not to do with webpack as I thought below - I was overwriting the gradient classes in the config by accident.

---

Is there any reason why a gradient like this one: `bg-gradient-to-r from-purple-500 to-pink-500`
would work in a [codepen](https://codepen.io/nwoodward/pen/poVbVOV?editors=1000), but wouldn't apply to my project? (uses webpack and a tailwind config file).

I've read a couple of solutions based around changing the config file to set up custom colors, but I'm a bit confused as to why it wouldn't just work out of the box? The element seems to be working fine (it'll take a bg color for example), and the gradient appears to be applying the classes:

[image: Tailwind classes]

I mean I can get it to work like this I guess? But I'm learning Tailwind so was interested if I was missing something

```
@layer{
 .grad  {
   background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #a855f7, #ec4899);
  }
 }
```

***Update**: added a small repo example [here](https://github.com/NickWoodward/gradient-example). I've added the gradient to the second section

****Update 2**: This doesn't happen when not using webpack, the gradient class works fine then. See [this](https://github.com/NickWoodward/tailwind-starter) minimal repo

Comment: If your new this might not be applicable, but some of the older versions of tailwind didn't include all the colours that we have today.

Comment: Yeah I'd read that too and thought the same given I've just started. Looks to be the newest: `"tailwindcss": "^3.1.6"`?

Comment: Maybe I'll try white to black - *Edit: nope, no luck

Comment: If white to black works, what I like to do is add custom colours into a theme.json file

Comment: Are your css changes being compiled?

Comment: Just happened to see this tagged in another post, maybe it will help! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67344478/tailwind-css-how-to-apply-background-image-with-linear-gradient

Comment: Yeah, all css is compiling fine, and the div I'm applying the gradient to can have the `bg-red-700` class applied to it no problem. The post you linked looks interesting for when I just have to get it working (it looks like it fixes my suggested fix), but I'm still interested why the tailwind class wont' work https://tailwindcss.com/docs/background-image#background-images

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding the answer in case someone else makes the same mistake.

So it turns out I'd accidently overwritten the gradient classes by using:

```
backgroundImage: {
  'hero-pattern-desktop': "url('/src/images/bg-header-desktop.png')",
  'hero-pattern-mobile': "url('/src/images/bg-header-mobile.png')"
},
```

outside of `extend`.

Credit to the Tailwind creator who got back to me real quickly: [here](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/issues/9332).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, tailwind config

```
export default {
     content: ['./index.html', './src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}'],
     theme: {
     extend: {
       backgroundImage: {
        landing: 'linear-gradient(rgba(35, 25, 23, .48), rgba(35, 25, 23, .48)), url(/src/assets/landing.jpg)',
        interior: 'linear-gradient(rgba(35, 25, 23, .48), rgba(35, 25, 23, .48)), url(/src/assets/interior.jpg)',
        church: 'linear-gradient(rgba(35, 25, 23, .48), rgba(35, 25, 23, .48)), url(/src/assets/church.jpg)',
       },
       },
    },
  plugins: [],
 };

 <div className="bg-landing"></div>
```