# Linear Gradient in Tailwind CSS

Tags: tailwind-css

I have this css `background: linear-gradient(159deg, #3CC 0%, #00AFCB 100%);`

how to convert it accordingly tailwind css ? I have done this -

```
<button class="py-2 px-6 bg-[linear_gradient(159deg, #3CC 0%, #00AFCB 100%)]">
        Download Now
</button>
```

But its not working.

Comment: `bg-[linear-gradient(159deg,#3CC_0%,#00AFCB_100%)]`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to apply background image with linear gradient in Tailwind CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67344478/how-to-apply-background-image-with-linear-gradient-in-tailwind-css)

Answer (score 0):

for background gradient check this out in tailwind docks: [gradient color stops](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/gradient-color-stops)

You should use [arbitrary values](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/gradient-color-stops#arbitrary-values)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this :

```
class="bg-gradient-to-r from-[#159DE0] via-[#33CCCC] via-0% to-[#00afcb] to-100% w-full"
```

Comment: Format your answer, use a code fence. You could also add a concise explanation why your code solves the problem.